# Font of the following article?

Tags: fonts

I really like the font/layout of the following article:

[http://www.econ.upf.edu/~apesteguia/RandomTypeModel.pdf](http://www.econ.upf.edu/%7Eapesteguia/RandomTypeModel.pdf)

I've tried various fonts/packages, but I don't seem to find the right one. Can you help me identify it?

Comment: Have you tried `\documentclass{amsart}`?

Comment: The font is the standard Computer Modern, you need no font package for it. The class seems to be `amsart` with increased baseline skip.

Comment: Thank you, amsart was exactly what I was looking for, great!